# Why my computer hang due to full consumption of ram memory?

Tags: ram, cpu, architecture

I have 3 Gb of Ram installed on my dell core 2 duo computer. 
The problem, I am facing is that my pc uses a lot of Ram memory. It have consumed 1 Gb space just at the start of computer. 
Moreover, it consumed all 3gb ram with just one firefox browser with 7*9 tabs opened on it. 
I am not getting the problem, IS it with my pc or any OS related problem . 
By the way I am using ubuntu 17.10 and processor is Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7400 @ 2.80GHz × 2 .

[image: This image link shows the status of ram just after the start of computer]

Comment: Gnome, the desktop of Ubuntu, is generally referred to as a big consumer of computer resources.  You may find that you would be better off with a lighter desktop environment, such as Lubuntu.

Comment: Nothing unusual for a ~10 years old hardware running a modern 3D desktop environment. The world changed a lot since, system requirements are way higher, web browsers use a lot more resources now, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when all 3GB of RAM gets used is that the kernel tries to free up RAM by putting certain pages in swap. If you have a hard drive, it means that instead of reading and writing to RAM, some programs require the kernel to pull things out of swap, which is slow, especially with a hard drive. If your swap partition is too small, the kernel may even begin to kill process as a last attempt to keep the system stable. I recommend you do the following:

Create a bigger swap file/partitions, which you can do with:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile; sudo mkswap /swapfile; sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Decrease your swappiness, which you can do with

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10; sudo swapoff -a; sudo swapon -a
```

and to make it permanent, edit /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and add

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

to the bottom.

The lower swappiness setting will tell the kernel to swap less, which may improve your performance a bit. The added swap will make your system a bit slower,rather than a complete crash, should you use a ton of RAM. You could also change your OS to something like Lubuntu, which is designed to work on lower-end computers. Or, you could just add more RAM :)

Note: As mentioned in the comment, the proper command to create a swap file is something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=4096
```

as `mkswap` doesn't like `fallocate`

Comment: Please note that `man mkswap` indicates that the use of fallocate on ext4 file systems is "not acceptable".

Comment: Oops, well it's faster than `dd`, and works from my experience :)

Comment: Yes, it is faster, however it appears that the use of the use pf preallocated files *can* cause difficulties with the resulting swap file.

Comment: Oh, that would explain my system crashes. Anyways, what's the best alternative: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=4096`?(bs is 1 MB, and count is for 4GB)

Comment: That's what I've used in the past, and it works OK.  May not be *best*, but since I run it only occasionally...  Also check permissions on your swapfile - should be 0600.  If you zero a current file, you will need to re-run mkswap

Comment: @NerdOfLinux can you tell me how to check my current  swap space ?

Comment: The picture you put shows 100 MiB, you can check with `free -h`